# Can stackoverflow create mirror sites for blocked f-droid apps?

Tags: android, port, tor, orbot

New information below:

I have been using Orbot for android for a while now and suddenly I was having issues with it stopping suddenly causing difficulty loading some sites.

So I uninstalled it and when I tried to re-install it from F-droid I got a notification that guardianproject.info website was blocked by an entity named a.ns.mayfirst.org and b.ns.mayfirst.org

So I then downloaded it from github but when I tried to install it my device took me BACK to the F-droid app where a popup said "needs authorization". But nowhere could I see how I could do that.

I also found information that the ttl: was set to 86400. But my device ttl performed at about 2 seconds thus timing out.
Either I need help changing my device ttl or I need a way to get around the block.
I must disclose I am not a developer, I am self-taught.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programmer related questions. You may have better luck at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) which is aimed at end-user and power user questions.

Comment: You can download Android APK files for Orbot directly from https://github.com/guardianproject/orbot/releases